# MVC 4 Lose Session Because Redirects From www.website.com to website.com

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, redirect

I just realize that session is lost when redirecting from www.website.com to website.com without www.

However I am quite lucky that I can set up the server so all redirection is start with www. In the future I do not want my application to be server dependent, I want to make it code dependent.

For example:

`@Html.Hidden("PageManagerUrl", Url.Action("PageManager","Admin"))`
produces `/Admin/PageManager/`, and I use location.href = url (when url is `/Admin/PageManager/`.

It is not 100% sure that I will lose my session at the first time of redirection, but when I tested it but redirecting back and forward, about the 3rd or 4th time, the session will be lost. After I set up the server setting to:

```
Preferred domain * www.website.com

Select the URL (either with or without the www. prefix) to which site visitors will be redirected via a SEO-safe HTTP 301 redirect.`
```

The session is never lost again. So I wonder, how to do the best redirection without losing my session? Please give me example how to do it from controllers and javascript / views.

Comment: Depending on your application pool settings, the session state may be lost if there was recycle process happen while redirection occurs. Probably you may try SQL Server session state management to manage user sessions based from session content saved in database.

Comment: There is no application pool recycling, I have checked them. It is because of something else

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any global.asax file ?

If yes, then please check whether it contains these two methods signature.

protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

Comment: I see this could be helpful, but what code should I insert on both function to determine what is the cause of the session end?